# Chosen Jquery : Change multiple chosen values separator to pipeline instead of comma

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

When multiples values are selected, the value of the multiple select chosen drop box is separated by comma.
Example:

```
var selectedValue=$('#field1').chosen.val();
```

The selectedValue is value1,value2,value3

But i want the selected value to be value1|value2|value3.

Is there a way to change the seperator from comma(,) to pipeline(|)??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$('#field1').chosen.val().join('|');` Since `.val()` returns an array you can use `join` to display the values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var selectedValue = $('#field1').val().join('|');
```